# How to know logical & primary in Partition table

Tags: partitioning

[image]

Please can anyone check my partition table? Is it a proper partition table?

Comment: You have GPT so there's no primary and logical. In a sense they're all primary.

Comment: @MichaelBay - You should post that as an answer perhaps with a linke to GPT partitions for reference.

Comment: And read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table